# javascript timer is resets while i am updating it into database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, timer, postback

i am working on a javascript timer..timer works fine but i want to update timer value into database when users unload the page but the problem is timer's initial value is updating into database not current value 
here is my code for javascript timer:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


    var t;

    function display() {

        if ((document.getElementById("<%=lblMin.ClientID%>").innerText == 0) && (document.getElementById("<%=lblSec.ClientID%>").innerText == 0)) {
                //if a popup window is used:
                setTimeout("self.close()", 1000);
                return;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("<%=lblSec.ClientID%>").innerText -= 1
                document.getElementById("<%=lblMin.ClientID%>").innerText = document.getElementById("<%=lblMin.ClientID%>").innerText
                document.getElementById("<%=lblSec.ClientID%>").innerText = document.getElementById("<%=lblSec.ClientID%>").innerText
                t = setTimeout("display()", 1000);
                if (document.getElementById("<%=lblSec.ClientID%>").innerText <= 0) {
                document.getElementById("<%=lblSec.ClientID%>").innerText = 60;
                    document.getElementById("<%=lblMin.ClientID%>").innerText -= 1;



                }

        }
    }
    window.onload = display;
```

on page unload code:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
    con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ashu\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Technoshine X.6\Technoshine X.6\bin\MCQ.accdb"



    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Open()
    End If

    cmd.Connection = con

    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Gamer" & " SET [TIME]='" & lblMin.Text & "',[SECOND]='" & lblSec.Text & "' WHERE [ID]='" & Me.lblUser.Text & "'"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()

End Sub
```

its not updating current value of timer its updating timers initial value 29 60...pls help me to resolve me this problem thanks in advance

Comment: Not related to your question but please dont do this: `t = setTimeout("display()", 1000);` that should be `t = setTimeout(display, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

The `unload` event is raised in the control life-cycle right before dispose. Since the page itself is a control the unload event is raised for it as well. Each control you add to the page will be part of the page life-cycle. So if you have a control that needs to do some cleanup, the control itself should handle any possible cleanup in itself. You should not have to worry about this, provided the control has been added to the page and properly follows the encapsulation principle.

you can try with javascript before browser close or tab close and send value with `AJAX`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'String';
};
```

---

try that:

first make your method webmethod by

```
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod>
Public Sub Webmethod()
   //get time object name "date" form request from and pass to commandText
End Sub


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/*webMethod url*/",//Url
            data: { date: new Date() }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Will close" );
            return 'String';
        });

    };
</script>
```

Comment: i don't have much idea about ajax specially how can i update database value using ajax can u help me to update value using ajax please